# How to get a random element in a given List in Elm?

Tags: random, elm

I'm building a sliding puzzle game:

[image]

From this initial position, I'd like to shuffle the puzzle, say 100 moves.

I'd like the puzzle to be shuffled differently each time.

This probably means that I need to call [`Random.initialSeed`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Random#initialSeed) with a different number every time, which means that I need to use something like the current time.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find how to get the current time.

In every given state, I have a list of possible moves. For example, in the initial position above: `[MoveRight, MoveDown]`

So, basically, my question is: how to get a random element in a given List?

[share-elm](http://share-elm.com/) example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rough answer (not near a compiler right now):

If you want to vary the seed based on the current time, add `Time.every` to your signal graph:

http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Time#every

Keep the last seen timestamp in your model, then, when you need to shuffle, use it to seed your random. Generate an integer in the range [1, length list], and then pick the element of that index.

Hope that's enough of a hint, please yell if it isn't and I will elaborate when I get chance.

Comment: Thanks for that! `Time.every` looks good. I didn't think about storing it in the model. My only concern is that I'll be modifying the model so many times, but use that value only a couple of times. What interval would you use? `Time.every 100`? `Time.every 10`?

Comment: I guess the interval depends on how frequently you expect to shuffle, and what sort of event triggers a shuffle. I'm starting to think that if it's user driven (by click, say) a different approach (using `Time.timestamp` to give all incoming events a timestamp) might be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks! `Time.timestamp Mouse.clicks` is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: One more thing: Say I want to initialize my model with a random seed. I guess I need to grab the initial signal value from `Time.timestamp`, but how?

Comment: Could you timestamp _all_ your events? You'll get a reasonable start value then, I think. Otherwise, you could consider using a port.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. My point is, imagine you don't have any events in the system, and you want something random to happen on every page load. In my case, for now, I just want to randomize the board on every page load.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are quite right: by default no event fires at page load time, so there's nothing to timestamp. We'll need to use a port: `port initialTime: Float` in the Elm piece, and then provide that value when constructing the Elm application in js `var myapp = Elm.fullscreen(Elm.YourAppName, { initialTime: Date.now() });`.

Comment: Don't base seeds off time since it's not uniformly distributed. Use `Math.floor(Math.random()*0xFFFFFFFF)` instead.

Answer (score 7):

This is a revision of pdamoc's answer. It follows The Elm Architecture more closely, but more importantly, it saves the random seed from press to press. If you keep using an initial seed, you won't get randomness. I got only even or odd numbers (got evens, refreshed, got odds) with the other version. It's important to call `Random.initialSeed` only once in your program, usually in the definition of the initial model.

There is also [a library](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mgold/Elm-Random-Sampling/2.0.2/Random-Array) (which I wrote) that handles random operations on Arrays.

```
import Html exposing (..) 
import Html.Events exposing (onClick) 
import Random exposing (initialSeed, int, generate, Seed)

type alias Model = 
  { list : List Int , currentElement : Maybe Int, seed : Seed}

init : Model 
init = {list = [1..10], currentElement = Nothing, seed = initialSeed 42 } 

type Action = NoOp | Click

actions : Signal.Mailbox Action
actions = Signal.mailbox NoOp

update : Action -> Model -> Model
update action model =
  case action of
    NoOp -> model
    Click ->
      let gen = Random.int 0 (List.length model.list - 1)
          -- since we know the list is constant we don't have to
          -- redefine the generator every time, but we will anyway
          (i, seed) = Random.generate gen model.seed
          elem = List.drop i model.list |> List.head
      in {model| currentElement <- elem, seed <- seed}

model : Signal Model
model = Signal.foldp update init actions.signal

view : Signal.Address Action -> Model -> Html
view address model = 
  let 
    current = model.currentElement
              |> Maybe.map toString
              |> Maybe.withDefault "NONE"
  in 
    div [] 
      [ text  <| toString model.list
      , br [] []
      , text  <| "Current Element: " ++ current
      , br [] []
      , button [onClick address Click ] [text "Click for Random Element"]
      ]

main = Signal.map (view actions.address) model
```

Comment: Please put the code directly in your post so your answer stays useful even when the link breaks.

Comment: @mgold Thanks for your answer. When clicking the button in your example I always get the same sequence, which completely misses the point of the question. I'd like to get a new sequence every time.

Comment: Then define `post seed : Int`, pass in a random int from JS, and use that instead of 42.

Comment: The use of `List.head` forces you to wrap the result in a Maybe, when in fact the value can be never be a `Nothing`. How would you fix this?

Comment: Either do case analysis on the Maybe with `Debug.crash` in the empty case, or use [`List.Nonempty.sample`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mgold/elm-nonempty-list/latest/List-Nonempty#sample).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a variant of Elm's StartApp sample, which includes the Time for every event, only when an event occurs.

https://gist.github.com/z5h/41ca436679591b6c3e51

Your update function will now look like:

`update : action -> Time -> model -> (model, Effects action)`